# Strategies In Computing Determinant?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Especially when solving for eigenvalues, since reducing to RREF is out of the question, are there any other strategies to compute the determinant quickly and more efficiently other than through cofactor (for example), multiplying/foiling/reducing all terms as best as I can, then solving for a quadratic/cubic (etc)? Not that this method doesn't work, it's just incredibly tedious and a time killer when I'm in a crunch. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Usually I try to create as many zeroes as I can by row/column reducing. Try to look for factors you can pull out of rows/columns. Then expand towards the row/column with the most zeroes. But in the end it is a calculation and might be annoying no matter what you do. Still, it's better than calculating an inverse.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but I guess I was asking for something that doesn't exist in the first place. Thanks!